# JavaScript - Removing last() doesn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a remove function that remove class. It  perform correctly except if it found a **duplicate**.

How could I solve the problem? Here is GIF's

Correct: https://gyazo.com/cdd6800f4f847d21d97a071241f76242

Duplicate name: https://gyazo.com/d166fcf19af8a147fcb2897bfeb695ed

Here's the code:

```
$('li img[title="' + removedname  + '"]:last').parent().parent().removeClass('red lighten-1 white-text selected-item');
```

HTML

```
<li class="col 2 zoomIn animated" style="padding: 8px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; animation-delay: 0s;">
   <div class="card item-card waves-effect waves-light red lighten-1 white-text selected-item" data-itemnaaaaaaaaaaaame="★ Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web (Field-Tested)" style="margin: 0%; min-height: 295px; width: 245.438px; border-radius: 15px; height: 245px;" id="2761454276">
      <div class="iteam" style="text-decoration: underline;text-align: left">Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web</div>
      <div class="condition" style="text-align: left;text-size:13px">Field Tested</div>
      <div class="center-align" style="padding:6%">
         <img title="★ Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web (Field-Tested)" draggable="false" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf0ebcZThQ6tCvq4iSqODxMajum25V4dB8xLjD9tjwjgK1_kZoYT30ctKVegM7NFyGrwK5yee90ZDt6ZmazHNluCQ8pSGKMl3kzfs/200fx200">
         <div class="" 'floatvalue'="">
            Float: 0.11503319442272186
            <div class="bitskinscomp" style="font-weight: normal;font-size:12px">BitSkins Price: $111.43 (You save: $-38.15)</div>
            <div class="buyer-price center-align">$149.58</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: We need to see a more complete JS and HTML sample to be able to help you

Comment: That's code which deletes it. HTML I'll add one second please.

Comment: I've added my HTML as well.

Comment: The code you've shown here works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/up9zyd40/

Comment: Hmm, for me it doesn't. Like you can see on the Gyazo GIF it doesn't remove it :/. Maybe you know any solution :)?

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is that you check the console for any errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: There's no errors. It just removes all of those classes if there is multiple by same name `selected`, but I just want it to remove one of them. That's why I wanted to use `last()`, but seemed it didn't worked.

Answer (score -1):

Use closest instead of :last

```
$('li img[title="' + removedname  + '"]').closest('.card').removeClass('red lighten-1 white-text selected-item');
```

Comment: I edited the code. It's now searching for '.card'. When I test it the classes are removed.

Comment: It removes all classes where is item with that name so basically still does same :/